# How to fix the intermittent issue when dealing with spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

We are using spring integration to poll the emails from outlook box.

Intermittently, we are seeing these exceptions.

**Javax.mail.MessagingException: A4400 NO Server Unavailable
javax.mail.MessagingException: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.;**

02:20:03.858 [task-scheduler-2] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: A4400 NO Server Unavailabl
e. 15;
  nested exception is:
        com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A4400 NO Server Unavailable. 15
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:131)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:224)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)

02:20:05.321 [task-scheduler-2] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.;
  nested exception is:
        com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.
: at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:131)

**Code snippet:**

@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow imapIdleFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
                Mail.imapInboundAdapter()
                    .searchTermStrategy((f, l) ->)
                    .javaMailProperties(p -> p
                        .put("mail.debug", )
                        .put("mail.imap.connectionpoolsize", ))

I don't get the solution When I surfed the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what server you're trying to connect to, but I ran into the "A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected" error with imap and outlook.office365.com. I tried to set up the same account in Outlook to make sure it was working in general. Although I was able to add the account, when I actually tried to look at the inbox Outlook became unresponsive. So in my case, it was a problem with the account in general, not with how I was trying to connect.  I was able to connect successfully with pop3 in case that's an option for you.